# Is there a statistical distribution whose values are bounded $[-1,1]$ and sum to 1?

Tags: distributions, dirichlet-distribution, bounds, sum

The Dirichlet distribution contains values that are bounded $[0,1]\in \mathbb{R}$ and sum to $1$. Is there a parametric distribution or similar method whose values do the same but reach as low as $-1$?

[Parallel discussion of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910689/transformed-dirichlet-array-with-range-1-1-in-numpy)

Comment: there's a parameter α for Dirichlet though. what should α=? to make that work

Comment: What do we put for $\alpha$

Comment: Whatever you wish it to be? I do not really understand the question. Maybe the question 'what do we put for ...' requires you to explain the situation a bit more. Because we can not know what $\alpha$ you want to put without more information than only the requirement that the distribution should be from -1 to 1

Comment: Maybe you should explain your underlying problem a bit more because currently your question is abstract (leading to an infinite possibilities) and it is unclear what the actual problem is or how specific you want it.

Comment: Everyone has gravitated to the scaled dirichlet, so im fine with working with it alone. Therefore no more infinite possibilities

Comment: 1: It is a bit tricky to gravitate towards a scaled Dirichlet. The Dirichlet distribution is just what you proposed yourselve in your question and what others have copied (but why do you propose it?). Furthermore, as I showed in my answer, a scaled Dirichlet distribution only works when the dimension is 3. It is also tricky because a question with so little specifications is troubling and not a good standard.

Comment: 2: If other people with a similar problem stumble on this question then they should not be automatically satisfied with the answers. For many problems you can not *just* pick any out of many distributions. Or at least it is not a good practice. You should have some argument/background/information how and where the distribution is applied (what should it do? what should it model?). You can not go solve a problem by asking people what $\alpha$ you should use without giving any information what you need it for.

Comment: i didnt propose dir. I only mentioned it as a similar case and had no idea it could be scaled to meet my requirements

Comment: You write *"...values do the same but reach as low as -1"*. You probably meant with 'the same' the sum up to 1, but it might be that you meant the Dirichlet distribution. .....Anyway, it doesn't matter who came up with it first. A scaled Dirichlet distribution does not always sum up to 1 (so it is not a correct/general answer)..... But you can, of course, always define a continuous distribution, or any other distribution, on the plane with normal vector $x_1+x_2+...+x_n = 1$, without scaling the Dirichlet distribution, but choosing any function.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that Dirichlet doesn't always sum up to 1, i thought it always did. by that do you mean it can sum to 0.9999999999, or it can sum to 0.8? and yes, you understood right, same as in, the only thing changed is the lower bound being -1 instead of 0, but still sum to 1

Comment: a *scaled* Dirichlet doesn't always sum up to 1.

Answer (score 9):

#### Scaling a Dirichlet distribution

If you want a variable that is distributed like a Dirichlet distributed variable but with a different range then you can scale and shift (transform the variable). This is effectively rescaling the axes.

To get from $[0,1]$ to $[-1,1]$ you can multiply by 2 and subtract 1. That is, your new variable $Y$ can be based on a regular Dirichlet distributed variable $X$ by the transformation

$$Y = 2X -1$$

(Where the transformation is done for each of the components, that is for every $y_i$ you compute $y_i = 2x_i-1$)

---

The probability density function will scale similarly but with an additional scaling factor (the density is less when you spread out over a larger range).

So the regular Dirichlet distributed variable $X$ has the density distribution $f_X$:

$$f_X(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{B(\boldsymbol{\alpha})} \prod_{i=1}^K x_i^{\alpha_i-1}$$

and the variable $Y = 2X-1$ has this density distribution $f_Y$:

$$f_Y(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{1}{2^K} f_X \left(\frac{\mathbf{y}+1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{B(\boldsymbol{\alpha})2^K} \prod_{i=1}^K \left(\frac{y_i+1}{2}\right)^{\alpha_i-1}$$

where $B(\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}) =\prod_{i=1}^K \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_i)}{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i)}$

---

So you do not need to change anything to $\alpha$. The transformation only requires scaling and shifting the axes (which also includes a scaling of the density by a factor $1/2^K$).

Whatever $\alpha$ needs to be will depend on your application.

---

#### When there is a constraint

> Is there a statistical distribution whose values are bounded [−1,1]
> **and sum to 1?**

Note: This transformation by scaling the axis is not always generally possible in case of your additional constraint.

Your additional condition requires $$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (a + b x_i) = an + b \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$$ and this only holds when $n = \frac{1-b}{a}$. With our straightforward transformation $a=-1$ and $b=2$ it does *not* hold. We need to use instead $a=1$ and $b=-2$, and then it will only work for a Dirichlet distribution with $n=3$.

The figure below shows this

[image: example]

The red plane is the domain of the 'regular' Dirichlet distribution.

The green plane is when you apply the transformation $y_i = 2x_i -1$, but then you do not get anymore that the variables sum up to 1. Instead the variables will sum up to -1.

The blue plane $y_i = 1 - 2 x_i$ will give you a transformation such that the sum is still 1.

#### A homogeneous distribution

Based on your stackoverflow question it seems that you are not looking for a distribution like the Dirichlet distribution, but you are looking for a homogeneous distribution (a special case of the Dirichlet distribution when all $\alpha_i =1$), where the pdf equals some constant $f(\mathbf{x}) = c$.

You can do this by rejection sampling or by an iterative computation of the coordinates $x_i$ where conditional/marginal distributions $f(x_i|x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{i-1})$ can be derived from rescaled and truncated versions of the Irwin Hall distribution. It is explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63922483) to your stackoverflow question.

Comment: "Do not need to change $\alpha$" assumes i already know what $\alpha$ should be before transformation but i don't. How about this: if I have $P$ variables and i set $\alpha$ equal to a vector of ones of length $P$, do i get what the question asks for?

Comment: @develarist *any* value will do.

Comment: But vector of ones will sample Dir uniformly won't it

Comment: @develarist Indeed a vector of 1s corresponds to a uniform distribution. It is unclear whether this matters. You'd need to explain/specify your question further for these details.

Comment: Uniformity is a go-to default in random sampling. Could you edit alpha of ones into ur answer (as an option for the user) since every package requires an alpha input. Why else would i ask everyone what is alpha

Comment: @develarist "What do we put for $\alpha$?" is a different question than "How can I choose $\alpha$ so that I can draw samples from a uniform Dirichlet distribution?" The second question provides *context* and *information* about what you want to achieve, where the first question is unfathomable. This is why each time you asked, people responded with a request for clarification.

Comment: it's alright that the extra step is being taken to make sure the answer complies with the application, but the question of how $x$ can be done, is separate from  the question of "does the answer to how $x$ can be done apply to task $A$"

Comment: @develarist Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need the variables to sum to one, you could "force it" by dividing by the sum. That is, if $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n$ are random variables, then the RVs
$$Z_i = \frac{X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$$
have the property that $\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i = 1$ (so long as $\sum X_i \neq 0$). This is easy to show.

$$\sum_{j=1}^n Z_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{X_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j = 1$$

---

```
N <- 10000
x <- 1 - 2*rbeta(N, 3, 3)
z <- x/sum(x)
w <- -1 + 2*(z-min(z))/(max(z) - min(z))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(x)
hist(z)
```

[image]

Comment: what distribution is `rbeta`?

Comment: Thats a Beta distribution with support on 0 to 1. I rescaled it to have support on -1 to 1. You can use any distribution appropriately scaled. Worth noting that the Dirichlet is a generalization of the Beta and reduces to the Beta distribution when there are just two random variables ($X$ and $1-X$).

Comment: does the transformed beta guarantee a sum of 1 as number of variables increases? the transformed Dirichlet was unable to guarantee a sum of 1.

Comment: If you define $Z_i = X_i/\sum X_i$, then you can guarantee that $\sum Z_i = 1$. It doesn't matter what distribution the $X_i$ have (as long as $\sum X_i \neq 0$). Please note: This may not be a good idea in some cases. Why is it so important that the variables sum to 1?

Comment: because 1 represents a 100% allocation of elements that are between -1 and 1. no one can possess more than 100% of something

Comment: But can somebody possess negative % of something? Why not just use a Dirichlet on 0 to 1? I think it would be helpful if you gave more details about your problem (perhaps in another question). Be careful to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: $1$ represents a 100% allocation in terms of total resources available amongst many partakers who are allotted separate $[-1,1]$ shares of those total resources, so i require a $-1$ lower bound

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a small mistake in @sextus-empiricus reply. I can't comment because of low karma, but the correction factor for the scaled-shifted Dirichlet should be $\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$. In the case of $k=2$ it matches an equivalent shifted-scaled Beta distribution.

This paper touches slightly on this: https://proceedings.mlr.press/v130/radul21a.html, and the TensorFlow probability implementation given the right results for a Scaled Dirichlet based on that work: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/1708